# Python - socket.gethostbyaddr() fails in one PC but works on another

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a Python script to get hostname for a list of IP addresses. The script works when I run from one computer but same script returns error (`[Errno 11004] host not found`) when run from another computer.

Both computers are W10 (v1809) with same Python version (3.7.4), sitting next to each other and connected to same corporate network. I don't even know where to look at for potential difference. Would appreciate any hints where/what I should be looking or if there's a different way to get hostname from IP.

Here's my code

```
    for ip in ipList:
        try:
            retVal = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
        except socket.error as serr:
            logger.debug('IP2Host for {} failed with Error {}'.format(ip, serr))
            retVal = 'FAILED'
        return retVal
```

Comment: Let's start from basics: are you able to ping the address from both computers?

Comment: Yes, I can ping. Average response time is 80ms.

Comment: And what if you ping them by hostname? I expect only one of them to succeed. In that case I would verify that  they refer to different DNS addresses, and one of them is not updated. I confess it is my last arrow..

Comment: Ping with hosthame returns ```Request timed out.``` for both.
Yeah this is weird but thanks for trying to help. Newbie here, so can't vote or thank.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to network settings.The hostname resolution is usually done by DNS ethernet protocole or hosts file and compare your netwotrk settings (ipconfig /ALL)

check the result of system command `nslookup ip` in a terminal.

Comment: Both computer give same result for ```nslookup ip```  
  
  
```Server:  <mydnsserver_dot_com>  
Address:  <mydnsserver_ip>  
  
*** <mydnsserver_dot_com> can't find <ip>: Non-existent domain```  
  
(removed server name and IP)  
  
Not sure if it matters both computers are in corporate domain.

Comment: may be  using traceroute may give you some helpful details about your network setup to watch the path and timings your packets are going : `tracert ip` that should permit to watch the path it takes to go to this . try to do the same with `tracert 8.8.8.8` (google dns) and compare